# disabled a div and sub elements and have tooltip on that

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to make a div and sub elements (what ever is like buttons span,...) disabled and have a tooltip on that for example (this section is disabled).

I just tried:

```
$(".divclass").css('pointer-events', 'none').css('opacity', '.4').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=50)');
```

The div and sub elements are disabled but I can't have a tooltip on that even title doesn't work.

Comment: Define “disable”. And of course you’re not getting a tooltip with the code you’ve shown any more, because with `pointer-events:none` you’re saying that those elements should not react to the (mouse) cursor in _any_ way …

Comment: So, what will be the soloution?

Comment: I asked you to define what you mean by “disabling” first, so please _do_ that!

Comment: Disable like the user can't use that element. for example if it is a link can't go to that link or so on. Disable like when you disable an input or a form element. But have tooltip on that.

Comment: Asking for a tooltip while also demanding _“the user can't use that element”_ is quite contradictory …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about covering the disabled elements with an overlay?

The following code creates a plugin that covers all the elements with an overlay. The "title" parameter is used to supply the "title" attribute for the overlay element.

```
$.fn.coverWithOverlay = function(title) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $element = $(this),
            pos = $element.offset();
        var $overlay = $('<div></div>').attr({
            title: title
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            opacity: 0.5,
            top: pos.top + 'px',
            left: pos.left + 'px',
            width: $element.outerWidth() + 'px',
            height: $element.outerHeight() + 'px'
        });
        $(document.body).append($overlay);
    });
}
```

You call the plugin like this:

```
$('.disabled').coverWithOverlay('this is disabled');
```

<kbd>[**Demo on JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbfV/3/)</kbd>

---

If this is a technique you want to utilize but want more functionality, you could use a library — like the [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).

Comment: I tried it.It covers the element next to it which is not disabled.

Comment: @Mark - Are you sure you are using the correct selector? The jsfiddle works fine. Can you create a jsfiddle that shows it not working?

Comment: @Mark - That fiddle does not use my code. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGLN4/) with the same HTML, but using my code.

Comment: If I have 3 elements that have same class to coveroverlay, how can I use that function one time for them?

Comment: I udpated the code so convertWithOverlay() is a plugin that works on multiple elements.